# Streaming large PDFs using .net and sftp server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to stream large PDFs (300 MB - 1GB). Right now I'm downloading them from an sftp server into a `MemoryStream`, and then streaming them to the browser. Its working fine for small Pdfs, but anything larger than 400MB opens the PDF viewer in the browser, the progress bar slowly moves to 100%, but the pdf never loads. If I get much larger than 500MB I get `SystemOutOfMemory` exceptions while downloading. Here is my relevant code

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var client = new SftpClient(sftpHost, port, username, password))
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.ChangeDirectory(envDirectory);
        using (memStream)
        {
            client.DownloadFile(fileName + extension, memStream);

            httpResponse.Clear();
            httpResponse.ClearContent();
            httpResponse.ClearHeaders();
            httpResponse.Buffer = true;
            httpResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Length", memStream.Length.ToString());

            memStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
            httpResponse.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

---UPDATE---

I took spender's advice and changed my code to

```
        using (var client = new SftpClient(sftpHost, port, username, password))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect();
                client.ChangeDirectory(envDirectory);
                httpResponse.Clear();
                httpResponse.ClearContent();
                httpResponse.ClearHeaders();
                httpResponse.Buffer = true;
                httpResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                client.DownloadFile(fileName + extension, httpResponse.OutputStream);
             }
```

This got rid of the out of memory exception, but larger pdfs still start loading and then stop with just a blank screen, smaller pdfs still work great.

SftpClient is from https://sshnet.codeplex.com/ client.DownloadFile(fileName + extension, httpResponse.OutputStream); returns void, but the second parameter is the Stream you want to dump the file into.

Any help, or better ways to do this would be great.

Comment: What is this `SftpClient`?

Comment: what does downloadfile return?....ienumerable?...object?

Comment: I've updated the main post to answer these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the `SftpClient` is not part of the BCL so I'm guessing a bit, but after you've added all the headers to your response, couldn't you just:

```
client.DownloadFile(fileName + extension, httpResponse.OutputStream);
```

skipping the `MemoryStream` altogether?

Comment: Skipping the MemoryStream got rid of the out of memory exceptions, but I still have the problem with it not loading the larger pdfs. It starts loading and then after awhile the loading bar goes away and I'm left with a blank screen.